# How to use validation for other button except than submit in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have written a html code for cshtml which consists two button save and update:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CustomActivity", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @id = "customActivityForm", @class = "activityForm" }))
                    {
                        <div>
                            <div class="container" id="activity">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Activity, new { @class = "" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Activity, new { @class = "w100p mb0" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Activity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="column one-fourth">
                                    <div>
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Rate, new { @class = "wcrate" })
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Rate, new { @class = "w100p mb0" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Rate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.WorkOrderId, new { @id = "hfWorkOrderId" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdminCustomActivity.Id, new { @id = "customActivityId" })
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="updateActivity">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }
                </div>
```

Now in the footer there is two button add and update the validation works perfect for add button but the validation dosen't works for Update button since the function call of update button is from jquery

```
 $("#updateActivity").click(function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/CustomActivity/Update",
                        data: {
                            WorkOrderId: @Model.Id,
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            location.reload();
                            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //alert(erro.data)
                        }
                    });
                })
```

How can I allow to check validation in update button same as add bututon. I tried using `type='submit'` but that doesn't works

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No that's the value of model in a razor view, it works as ``` @Model.Id ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to call a function which implements the [jQuery validatation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to show validation messages at the Update button click:

```
function validateUpdate() {      
  $("#customActivityForm").validate({
    rules: {
        AdminCustomActivity_Activity: "required",
        AdminCustomActivity_Rate: "required"
     }
  });
}

$("#updateActivity").click(function () {
      validateUpdate();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/CustomActivity/Update",
          data: {
              WorkOrderId: @Model.Id,
             },
          success: function () {
            location.reload();
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          },
          error: function () {
             //alert(erro.data)
          }
     });
})
```

Comment: Yes It validates the required field and shows error messages but after  showing error message it is still calling the API through ajax. Is there any way to call API through ajax only if there aren't any validation error?

Comment: I used if (validateUpdate()) { ///ajax call } but it didn't worked

Comment: I think you can use `if($("#customActivityForm").valid())`